# Reflection of light from a vertex of of a cube to another

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABCD$ and $BCFG$ be two faces of a cube with $AB=12.$ A beam of light emanates from vertex $A$ and reflects off face $BCFG$ at point $P,$ which is 7 units from $\overline{BG}$ and 5 units from $\overline{BC}.$ The beam continues to be reflected off the faces of the cube. The length of the light path from the time it leaves point $A$ until it next reaches a vertex of the cube is given by $m\sqrt{n},$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers and $n$ is not divisible by the square of any prime. Find $m+n.$

Here's the following solution:

It moves $5$ to the side and $7$ up, and we must end up at another vertex. Every time it reflects, it will move $5$ units to the side and $7$ units either up or down. If it hits a face partway through a reflection, it will continue the remaining number of units in the opposite direction. We first have that both $5x$ and $7x$ are multiples of $12$ for $x=12$. The length $AP$ is $\sqrt{5^2+7^2+12^2}=\sqrt{218}$, so we multiply that by $12$, and we have $12\sqrt{218}\Rightarrow 12+218=\boxed{230}$.

---

However, I can't se that every time it reflects, it will move $5$ units to the side and $7$ units either up or down.

Comment: Hint: imagine yourself being in the cube. You will actually see an infinite lattice of cubes, due to reflexion. Suppose there really _is_ an infinite lattice of cubes. Light will still appear to travel in straight lines! So you only need to see how far you have to extend $AP$ to reach another lattice point.

Comment: @Trebor Ok, thank you. I understood. It's very similar to the 2D one.

Comment: Not the same, but similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830671/distance-of-ray-reflection-inside-a-unit-cube/2831293#2831293